# How to impute missing values for multiple columns using a regressor?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, missing-data, imputation

This is an example of a larger dataset I have.

Imagine I have a dataframe with different columns and every column present missing values (NaN) in some part.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5],
                   'b':[4, 3, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, 6, 5, 8, 7, 4],
                   'c':[20, 25, 35, 30, 10, 18, 16, 22, 26, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

I would like to predict these missing values using RandomForestRegressor, for example, with the other columns as features.  In other words, when I see a sample with NaN, I want to use the value on the other two columns as features to predict this missing value.

I usually can do this for an unique feature, but I would like an automated way to do this for every column.

Thank you.

Comment: sounds weird to me. are the features have any link? Normally this fill technique you use only the same column and go with the mean or whatever. How do you wanna start? If you do it for the first column, this values will be uses for the second one...

Comment: In the real dataset, the features have relevant relations between them. The problem is that many of them have missing values and I can't simply remove them. I need to find a good way to estimate these values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `IterativeImputer` from sklearn and provide the `RandomForestRegressor` for it in the estimator parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5],
                   'b':[4, 3, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, 6, 5, 8, 7, 4],
                   'c':[20, 25, 35, 30, 10, 18, 16, 22, 26, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

imp_mean = IterativeImputer(estimator=RandomForestRegressor(), random_state=0)
imp_mean.fit(df)
display(pd.DataFrame(imp_mean.transform(df)))
```

This will then return the following dataframe, in which the nan values are imputed accordingly:

```
0   1   2
0   0.300   4.00    20.00
1   0.200   3.00    25.00
2   0.500   5.00    35.00
3   0.100   3.69    30.00
4   0.400   5.53    10.00
5   0.500   5.78    18.00
6   0.389   5.00    16.00
7   0.455   6.00    22.00
8   0.463   5.00    26.00
9   0.600   8.00    21.02
10  0.300   7.00    16.92
11  0.500   4.00    29.98
```

Comment: That's definitely what I need. Thank you very much, @Kim Tang!